# Currency conversion in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

I have an ecommerce site with multi language.

I am handling the multi-language translation using the I18n API; like this:

```
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = session[:locale]
end
```

This is pretty useful with static texts, so I can have different dictionaries to separate the texts.

How ever, this is an ecommerce; so price variables are needed.

I am trying to use mexican pesos and US dollars

The price is storaged in MXN in database.

I also have one option in the database with the mxn_to_usd value.

So 1 USD = 18 MXN.

Right now, to display prices; I am doing this:

```
number_to_currency(disc.price, :unit => "$")
```

But this only works for one currency.

What i've tried is to rewrite the number_to_currency method; so when the I18n.locale is "EN" it converts the MXN (the one stored in DB) to US dollars.

But no success yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is to use exchange rates, I recommend you to use the `money` gem https://github.com/RubyMoney/money and you can load your exchange rates like:

> ```
> Money.add_rate("USD", "CAD", 1.24515)
> Money.add_rate("CAD", "USD", 0.803115)
> Money.us_dollar(100).exchange_to("CAD")  # => Money.new(124, "CAD")
> Money.ca_dollar(100).exchange_to("USD")  # => Money.new(80, "USD")
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ultra lightweight [concurrency](https://github.com/naman2202/concurrency) gem which provides you with the basic conversion functionality using methods like:

```
Concurrency.convert(100, "USD", "INR")  # would convert 100 dollars to Indian Rupees
Concurrency.conversion_rate("USD", "INR")  # would convert 1 USD to INR
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems the easiest and best.